# SwiftUI How to append a view to an existing view

Tags: swiftui

I have an existing ScrollView view with a Picker. Upon selection of a picker value, and user pressing the details button, I want to append a view to the bottom of the existing view.
I call detailsView, but won't display the Text. Also can't step into it in debug mode.
Instead of calling DetailsView I replaced it with   Text("Some Details"). Even then it wont display

```
Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@Binding var chosenProvider: Provider?

@State var selectedLocation: Location?

@State private var vendorNames: [String] = []
@State private var selectedVendor:String? = nil


@State private var showingSheet = false

@State var state: String?
@State var zip: String?


var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack  {
            HStack {
                Text("Select Vendor")
                
                Picker("Provider", selection: $selectedVendor  , content: {
                    ForEach(vendorNames,id: \.self, content: { name in
                        Text(name)
                    })
                })
                .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.getVendorNames() { providers, status in
                        if (status) {
                            vendorNames = providers
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
            .onChange(of: selectedVendor, perform: { newValue in
                selectedVendor = newValue
                
            })
            .tint(.orange)
    
                Button {
                    DetailsView()
                } label: {
                    Label("Details", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
      
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
        .onAppear{
            self.getVendorNames() { providers, status in
                if (status) {
                    vendorNames = providers
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add Vendor")
        .toolbar {
            // Back button
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {  presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }, label: {
                    HStack(spacing: 2) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        Button("Back", action: {
                            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        } )
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                })
            }
           
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}

struct DetailsView:  View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack  {
                Text("Some Details")
            }
        }
}

func getVendorNames (completionHandler: @escaping ([String], Bool) -> Void ) {
  var names = ["Acme", "Abc"]
  
    completionHandler(names, true)
       
}
```

}

Comment: You are creating the view in the button action.  You need to trigger a review refresh in the action that then displays the DetailsView, not actually create it there.

Comment: Are you getting this warning `Result of 'DetailsView' initializer is unused` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong approach for displaying the `DetailsView`. That's not how views are displayed in `SwiftUI` when the user clicks a button.

First, you need a state variable that will hold the value of whether the `DetailsView` is shown or not:

```swift
@State private var showDetailsView = false
```

Second, change your details button action to look like this:

```swift
Button {
    // This will refresh the view by triggering its update
    showDetailsView = true
    
} label: {
    Label("Details", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
}
```

Then, wherever you want to display the `DetailsView` , you can just do:

```swift
// ... whatever view 
if showDetailsView {
    DetailsView()
}
Spacer()
// ... other view
```

If you want to learn more, check: [dynamically hiding a view](https://www.devtechie.com/community/public/posts/231541-dynamically-hiding-view-in-swiftui) and [how to present a new view in swiftui](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets)